# Expose Lightning .app publicly?

Tags: force.com-sites, lightning-apps

Is there any way to expose Lightning .app publicly ? I enabled Lightning components on my dev org and was thinking to do it via force.com sites but I couldn't find a way. Perhaps there is a way to put the Lightning app inside a visualforce page somehow and then in this way I can share the VF page on a Force.com Site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At this time Lightning Apps are only for SF1 Mobile. Edited to add that they're single page apps, so embedding them would not be possible anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I have to make it with visualforce than. Any idea if such a functionality is planned to be released in the future?

Comment: It's in their long term plan, but I have no idea as to how soon to expect it. Reports and other platform features are already built around lightning technology. Safe Harbor as SF would say.

Comment: You can use Lightning Apps from Visualforce pages via the apex:iframe tag. They don't work for Force.com sites as yet, which I believe is due to the permissions of the Guest user profile.

Comment: @BobBuzzard Is it still the case that Lightning Apps/components cannot be used in Force.com sites?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor, they can be used in Communities, but the W16 release notes said they couldn't be exposed in public facing Sites.

Comment: Is there any update on this? Can we use lightning components on site pages via lightning out?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, lightning is not supported at this time for Sites. It appears that Sites are apparently still served from visualforce page servers. Communities are fully supported with lightning, including for the Guest Only User license, but for some reason, I can't find any reference to lightning being Supported for Sites. Log-in pages are still visualforce for both.

Answer (score 10):

@everyone as part of spring 17 Lightning components can be added to unauthenticated sites using lightning out. below is the link

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_lightning_apps_public.htm

> "Add the `ltng:allowGuestAccess` interface to your Lightning Out
>   dependency app to make it available to users without requiring them to
>   authenticate with Salesforce."

Technical implementation details are mentioned in the above link.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add detail to the answer as the question did specifically mention a force.com site.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_lightning_apps_public.htm

The org needs to be communities enabled. Based on that, I'm inferring that you can use lighting.out only against a *community* and not a 'solo' force.com site.  It seems force.com sits are being encouraged to sunset IMHO.

Comment: I created a POC for that and lightning out also works with no community being enabled.

Comment: Interesting,, Did that work for both unauth and auth'd users?

Comment: I just tested this with unauthenticated users....

Comment: @JannisBott Would you mind sharing your vf page on how you exposed the page on the force.com site.