# My Active site home page is not visible. It is showing the default template instead

Tags: visualforce, force.com, force.com-sites

This is my code that I have added to the link of active home page while creating a new site.[image: The Screen shot shows the default template]

```
    <apex:page >
           <apex:includeLightning />
                <div id="lightning" />
                <script>
                $Lightning.use("c:CTD_TestApp", function() {
                    $Lightning.createComponent("c:CTD_LoginPage",
                                               {},
                                               "lightning",
                                               function(cmp) {
                                                   console.log("Component created!");
                                                   console.log(cmp);
                                               });
                });

       </script>
   </apex:page>
```

This is the App.

```
 <aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" >
        <aura:dependency resource="c:LoginPage"/>
 </aura:application>
```

It shows my internal server error 500 on the app that is not loading. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the app code to : implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess" was missing.

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:LoginPage"/>
</aura:application>
```

Follow this link to know more,

[Exposing Lightning app on force.com sites](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178761/exposing-lightning-app-on-force-com-sites)